# Display product attributes in cms block or page builder

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, cms-block, variables, page-builder

I need to be able to reference product attributes inside a cms block or page builder, I am not wanting to create any template files I am wanting to call it like you can call a variable.

So here is one of Magento's standard variables which outputs the base url from the config.

{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}

What I need to know is there anyway you can do this for product attributes.

Or if someone knows how to create a set of custom variables which call the data from a product attribute would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end we created a custom module which you could call the attributes via a widget into page builder or any content blocks.

Comment: Any chance this code/module is publicly available on GitHub?

Comment: Currently there is no GitHub repo for this but I will see if the company I work for will allow this to be shared.

Answer (score 0):

use this code in phtml file to call your attribute –

```
<?php
/**
 * @var Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View $block
 */
$product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<h1 style="color: #1979c3">Brand:<?php echo $product->getData('brand'); ?></h1>
```

Comment: use this code in phtml file to call your attribute

Comment: As per my question I don't want this done in a phtml file but inside a cms block as I already know how to achieve this in a phtml file, but thanks for the response.

Comment: please let us know when you find your answer

Comment: seems like I am going to have to make a module to achieve this, would have thought you would be able to call these easily.

Comment: In the end we had to create a module to achieve this.